# Install Open JDK and SunJDK and choose while launching an application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, intellij-idea, ubuntu-12.04, java

Intellij Idea CE recommends Sun Java on Ubuntu 12.04. Amazon EC2 API Tools comes packed with OpenJDK and if you try to uninstall OpenJDK amazon ec2 api tools uninstalls with it to.

How to install both Java and start IntelliJ with Sun and Amazon tools with Open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

shouldn't it be really straightforward ?

Install the sun jdk, and then afterwards change the default jdk using

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Comment: If I set Sun Java as default will it be ok with amazon ec2 api tools.

Comment: In my experience yes, the AWS API Tools work just fine under the Sun/Oracle JVM (they just use OpenJDK because of the licensing restrictions that make it difficult to build the Oracle JVM in as part of the instance)